# Event on the button with Radio Button

Tags: java, android

How can I make several events in one single button? I am not able, do another event on the same button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvhOd.png)

And for example, according to 1 radion button:

```
public void onRadioButtonLetterA(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    if (count == 0) {
        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.letterA:
                if (checked) {
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else if (count == 1) {
        count = 1;
        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.letterA:
                if (checked) {
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

And on the button:

```
public void checkButton(View view) {

  if (count == 0) {
      TextView sumSettlementTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumSettlementTextView);
      sumSettlementTextView.setText(String.valueOf(sumSettlement));

      TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countTextView);
      countTextView.setText(String.valueOf(count));

  }

  if (count == 1) {
 //Code  
  }
}
```

That is, if the `count == 0`, and click the Button, and radion button being selected,
will determine such a thing, the 2nd time you click, if the `count == 1`, and click the Button, and radion button, be selected,
It will do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep track of the number of clicks

```
int nbClicks = 0;
...
// in your button's onClickListener
if(nbClicks == 0) {
  // do something
  nbClicks += 1;
} else if (nbClicks == 1){
  // do something else
  nbClicks += 1;
}
...
```